# TextViews do not Stretch to MATCH_PARENT

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing an Android app that requires me to programmatically add a TextView to a TableRow which is, in turn, added to a TableLayout. For the design to look proper, the TextView width must be the same as the TableRow width. The problem I am having is that even though I have attempted to set the width of the TextView to match using `MATCH_PARENT`, it is not taking effect.

Here is a sample of the Java that I am trying to use to do this:

```
final TableRow myTableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

final TextView myTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
myTextView.setWidth(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
myTextView.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
myTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
myTextView.setTextSize(30);

myTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

myTextView.setText("1");

myTableRow.addView(myTextView);

myTableLayout.addView(myTableRow); // Assume 'myTableLayout' has already been declared.
```

Here is the XML for `myTableLayout`:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myTableLayout">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRowOne">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/textViewOne"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRowTwo">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTwo"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableRowThree">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewThree"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Here is a picture of the way the layout appears. **The code posted here is not identical to the actual app code, but it is enough to show the problem. Specifically, the code that was removed concerns the replies. In the example code posted as part of the question, only one TextView is shown in the Java code, but in the actually project, there are two.**

[Layout Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0hSq.png)

Comment: You aren't setting match parent for the table row you created. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @JyotmanSingh I can try it, but the TableRow background matches the width of the TableLayout.

Comment: can you share the layout image?

Comment: @Pooya I've added it to the question.

Comment: @DavidB: each row in the layout you have shown, there is just one TextView that is displayed like that or multiple textviews?

Comment: @Pooya Except for the first green row which has three TextViews, all of the other rows have two.

Comment: @Pooya I've also noticed that the maximum TextView width taken on by the other rows seems to depend upon whatever the largest width of one of the three TextViews is in the first row.

Comment: @DavidB: is there newline character ("\n") in your texts? specially the third one I mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108123/discussion-between-pooya-and-davidb).

Comment: @Pooya None of the display strings have newlines.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can handle this.

1. `TableLayout` and `TableRow` both extends `linearlayout`, so maybe you need to set Orientation.
2. you could set the layout params(margin params) like this

   ```
   layout_width = 0dp ;
   layout_weight = 1 ;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to give height and width property to a view is to use Layout Parameters. most of times (almost all the times for me) setting width and height directly wont work.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams mParam=new TableRow.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// set layout parameter to view
textView.setLayoutParams(mParam);
```